# How to make site point to https version using MVC

Tags: php

Before using MVC, I just used to use this line to make the url go to https. So, if the user typed in www.example.com it would take them to https://example.com

```
  RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R]
```

However, when trying to do this with my MVC website, typing in www.example.com takes me to that url and doesn't redirect to https. I have to manually type in https://mexample.com to go to the https version. How can I fix this?

In my root, my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R]
</IfModule>
```

Then in my public folder my .htaccess look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options -Multiviews
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /public
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally avoid doing this in .htaccess as I like to have the flexibility of a setting within the application to force it or not, plus I use reverse proxy and Cloudflare, so doing so would force me to setup end2end certificates between app servers and locks me into using apache2 instead of nginx or caddyserver.

So I just do it in PHP in the base controller, for example:

```
// is https
$https = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    $https = true;
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
    $https = true;
}

// is not https but required as https in config
if (!$https && $this->f3->get('app.security.force_https') === true) {
    exit(header('Location: '.$this->f3->get('site.url'), 302));
}
```

If you want to do it in .htaccess, something like:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Forcing `https://`                                                 |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Redirect from the `http://` to the `https://` version of the URL.
# https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```